# Compiling quantum gis dtclassifier c++ plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, gis, qgis

Quantum GIS (qgis) is an open source GIS software. The functionality of qgis can be extended by plugins written in python or c++. This question is related to the [DTClassifier](http://gis-lab.info/qa/dtclassifier-eng.html) which is c++ based. DTClassifier make it possible to automate the classification of raster maps, such as automate the classification of forests on remote sensed data.

I want to install the plugin on qgis 1.8.0 (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit), that is done by placing the compiled linux [DTClassifier plugin file](http://svn.gis-lab.info/dtclassifier/trunk/bin/dtclassifier-linux.tar.bz2) into

```
/usr/lib/qgis/plugins
```

However, that is a 32-bit binary сompiled under 32-bit Slackware 13.1 using OpenCV 2.3.1 while my os is Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. Puting the file into

```
/usr/lib/qgis/plugins
```

is not recognized by qgis. Maybe because I have 64-bit os and OpenCV 2.4.1. So I tried to compile the provided source code but failed to do so. **Anybody who could provide me with help how to compile the plugin or provide a already compiled file?**

This is what I have accomplished so far:

I installed OpenCV 2.4.1, and Qt4, and downloaded the source for DTClassifier

```
svn co http://svn.gis-lab.info/dtclassifier/trunk dtclassifier
```

This source was put into the qgis-1.8.0 source. Then cmake was run with the CMakeLists.txt:

I found this [(forum message)](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2011-September/015882.html) which is points to a 64-bit version for Ubuntu 11.04, but I could not make it work.

The details of what I have tried so far can be found below:

```
~/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier cmake .
```

The CMakeLists.txt

```
# set path to additional CMake modules
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4)
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

########################################################
# Files

SET (CLASSIFIER_SRCS
 classifier.cpp
 classifierdialog.cpp
 classifierutils.cpp
 rasterfileinfo.cpp
 layerselectordialog.cpp
)

SET (CLASSIFIER_UIS
 classifierdialogbase.ui
 layerselectordialogbase.ui
)

SET (CLASSIFIER_MOC_HDRS
 classifier.h
 classifierdialog.h
 layerselectordialog.h
)

SET (CLASSIFIER_RCCS  classifier.qrc)

########################################################
# Build

QT4_WRAP_UI (CLASSIFIER_UIS_H  ${CLASSIFIER_UIS})
QT4_WRAP_CPP (CLASSIFIER_MOC_SRCS  ${CLASSIFIER_MOC_HDRS})
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(CLASSIFIER_RCC_SRCS ${CLASSIFIER_RCCS})

ADD_LIBRARY (classifierplugin MODULE
${CLASSIFIER_SRCS}
${CLASSIFIER_MOC_SRCS}
${CLASSIFIER_RCC_SRCS}
${CLASSIFIER_UIS_H}
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
 ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
 ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR}
 ../../core/raster
 ../../core/renderer
 ../../core/symbology
 ../../core
 ../../gui
 ..
 .
 #/usr/include/opencv2
 )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(classifierplugin
 qgis_core
 qgis_gui
 ${OpenCV_LIBS}
 #/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so
 #/usr/lib/libopencv_ml.so
 #/usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
 #/usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
)


########################################################
# Install

INSTALL(TARGETS classifierplugin
RUNTIME DESTINATION /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
LIBRARY DESTINATION /usr/lib/qgis/plugins
)
```

It did not give any error

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier
```

. But then make fails complaining a lot:

```
make
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/classifierplugin.dir/classifier.cpp.o
In file included from /qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../gui/qgisinterface.h:40:0,
from /qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/classifier.cpp:23:
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:30:19: error: variable ‘CORE_EXPORT QGis’ has initializer but incomplete type
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:30:19: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:32:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘public’
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:32:3: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘public’
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:32:3: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘public’
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:38:22: error: uninitialized const ‘QGIS_VERSION_INT’ [-fpermissive]
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:77:47: error: storage size of ‘qgisVectorGeometryType’ isn’t known
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:80:41: error: storage size of ‘qgisFeatureTypes’ isn’t known
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:108:25: error: uninitialized const ‘DEFAULT_IDENTIFY_RADIUS’ [-fpermissive]
/qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier/../../core/qgis.h:109:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/classifierplugin.dir/classifier.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/classifierplugin.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

**Compiling DTClassifier c++ plugin on Quantum GIS (qgis) version 1.8.0 Ubuntu 64 bit.**

This is a short explanation of how I compiled the DTClassifier plugin on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. It might not be best practice but it worked!

**Getting the source code**

Find out which version of qgis is compatible with the plugin. In the documentation of the DTClassifier it has been compiled and tested on qgis 1.8 on 32-bit Slackware 13.1 using OpenCV 2.3.1. My point of departure was to first of all make qgis compile on my system. So I found this [excellent guide](http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html#toc3) on compiling qgis I followed step 1 - 3.7 in the guide except that I did not use the source suggested in step 3.6 from

```
git://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS.git
```

which is qgis 1.9 but here we need **qgis 1.8**. So instead download the source of qgis version 1.8 which I downloaded from ["7 Sources and Sample Datase"](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#71-Source-Code) 1.8 Final Release.(The instructions of how to compile is also provided in the source code archive as file "INSTALL".)

**Notes on my experience of compiling qgis.**

I had some trouble with proj and/or gdal libraries. At first I had a higher version of gdal libraries but with gdal 1.7.3 and proj 4.8 (reported by synaptic but proj command reports version 4.7) After sorting out proj/gdal trouble the compilation was successful and it was possible to try qgis.

If you get en error trying to execute the compiled qgis file this might help you: 
error while loading shared libraries: [libqgis_core.so.1.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Building_QGIS_from_Source)

**On to compiling DTClassifier**

DTClassifier depends on OpenCV libraries. I Installed and tested OpenCv 2.4.1 by following this excellent guide [installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts](http://www.samontab.com/web/2012/06/installing-opencv-2-4-1-ubuntu-12-04-lts/).

The source of DTClassifier is placed into

```
qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/dtclassifier
```

Then to the cmakelist file in the plugins directory needs information that also DTClassifier should be built:

```
qgis-1.8.0/src/plugins/CMakeLists.txt
```

this line was added

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(dtclassifier)
```

Then the compilation process of qgis was repeated. Remember to run "ccmake .." from step 3.7 in the INSTALL guide so that the configuration information is updated. Now the configuration should have lines that contain the configuration of OpenCV libraries. This time "make" runs faster because of the previous compilation.

In qgis the DTclassifier plugin should now appear as DTclassifier in the qgis Plugin Manager. However I run the plugin in the ubuntu apt-get version of qgis 1.8.0. so the resulting compiled DTClassifier file

```
qgis-1.8.0/build-master/output/lib/qgis/plugins/libclassifierplugin.so
```

needs to be placed in the qgis plugins directory (usually "/usr/lib/qgis/plugins").

**It worked for me hopefully it works for you also!**

Note: if you try to compile DTClassifier against qgis 1.9 then you most probably will get a list of errors similar to this:

```
 classifierdialog.cpp:328:13: error: ‘class QgsVectorDataProvider’ has no member named ‘select’
```

That is because the API of qgis classes has changed for version 1.9?